# How do I get this custom validator to work?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Having trouble with a custom validator pattern.  The essential elements for a successful validation should be 1) At least 1 number at the beginning 2) a space after the number/numbers 3) At least 1 alpha character that represents the street name.  Anything appended beyond that should still validate as true.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      street:['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d+\s*[a-zA-Z].*$/ig)]],
      city:['',Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required],
      zip:['',Validators.required],
      notes:[''],
    })
```

`44 North Road #12` validates but `44 North Road #123` Does not.  Essentially after I type in `44 North Road` every other character typed in (no matter what it is) makes the it fail validation until a subsequent character is entered and then fails again as the next character is typed.  It just ping pongs back and forth between invalid and valid as I add characters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your regex is a little off. Here is a simpler expression that matches your criteria:

```
^\d+\ [A-Za-z].*$
```

- `\d+`: one digit
- `\` (space afteer `\`): space
- `[A-Za-z]`: one alpha character
- `.*` anything else

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/SQHngi/1), where I added capture groups around your 3 specific criteria.

Comment: I think maybe it's a bug angular validators works.  It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working now.  Had /ig at the end and that was screwing things up.  Thanks for your help!